# How to add a SmartTag to Outlook 2010?

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, smart-tags

I would like to add smart tag support in the read message window of Outlook 2010. What's the best way of doing so? Are there examples anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has lots of examples of Office interop, check with MSDN and search for Office interop.

Here's one such article that might help your situation: [How To Programmatically Add a Smart Tag to a Word document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178787.aspx).

Comment: But will this also add to to Outlook, not just to Word?

Comment: No, you'd modify the code to work on Outlook, not Word. If you're having trouble getting started, read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23cw517s.aspx